# Как узнать доступен ли файл для открытия и записи?

Tags: c#

Есть папка в сети, в которой периодически создаются файлы. Есть необходимость копировать данные файлы в другой каталог. Нужно проверять, доступен ли файл для копирования, т.е. не дописывается ли он. Есть ли возможность проверить доступен ли файл для записи? Для примера, я открываю файл через Adobe Reader, данный файл не должен копироваться. Мне нужен ответ скорее на вопрос "Как узнать, открыт ли файл другой программой для изменения?"

Comment: Для примера, файл может открыться программой Adobe Reader. Мне нужно знать, что данный файл копировать нельзя.

Comment: А если изменяющий процесс откроет ваш файл сразу после того, как проверка дала ответ - "можно копировать"? Более грамотный подход - копировать все, потом проверять результат сравнивая (например) длину файлов.

Comment: Можно как вариант, но при больших размерах файла и длительной обработки сторонней программы думаю, что копирование займет времени куда больше. К примеру, опрос через каждую минуту, а файл 50 Мб обрабатывается пользователем 1 час - будет скопирован 60 раз... Ну зачем это? На каждом этапе у меня есть свои проверки и этот вариант, что вы написали я учитываю, проверяю дату последнего изменения после копирования, а после копирования файл удаляется... В общем, многое учтено. НО! Мне не нужно знать открыт сторонней программой или нет. Вопрос только в этом.

Comment: Я понимаю, что увожу Вас в сторону от прямого решения запрошеного вопроса, заранее извините. Но в описаной ситуации лично я не стал бы "изобретать велосипед", а просто воспользовался бы одной из готовых программ синхронизации файловых систем - слишком много тут "подводных камней".

Comment: Вариант не плохой. На данный момент удалось решить данный вопрос. Как говорится "все гениальное просто". Одно скажу, что здравого решения по моему вопросу нет.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать библиотеку со странным названием Restart Manager. Пример получения списка процессов, занявших файл  (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-know-the-process-704839f4):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace RMTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmStartSession(out UInt32 pSessionHandle, UInt32 dwSessionFlags,
            string strSessionKey);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmRegisterResources(UInt32 dwSessionHandle,
        UInt32 nFiles,string[] rgsFilenames,UInt32 nApplications,
        UInt32 rgApplications,UInt32 nServices,UInt32 rgsServiceNames);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32 RmGetList(UInt32 dwSessionHandle,  out UInt32 pnProcInfoNeeded,
        ref UInt32 pnProcInfo,[In, Out] RM_PROCESS_INFO[] rgAffectedApps,ref UInt32 lpdwRebootReasons);

        [DllImport("Rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, PreserveSig = true, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern UInt32  RmEndSession(UInt32 dwSessionHandle);

        const UInt32 RmRebootReasonNone = 0x0;

        /*Получение списка процессов, имеющих блокировку на файле*/
        static public List<Process> GetLockProcesses(string path)
        {
            uint handle;
            string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();
            uint res = RmStartSession(out handle, (uint)0, key);
            if (res != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not begin restart session. " +
                                    "Unable to determine file locker.");
            }
            try
            {
                const int ERROR_MORE_DATA = 234;
                uint pnProcInfoNeeded = 0, pnProcInfo = 0,
                    lpdwRebootReasons = RmRebootReasonNone;
                string[] resources = new string[] { path };
                res = RmRegisterResources(handle, (uint)resources.Length,
                                            resources, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                if (res != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not register resource.");
                }

                res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo, null,
                                ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                if (res == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
                {
                    // Create an array to store the process results. 
                    RM_PROCESS_INFO[] processInfo =
                        new RM_PROCESS_INFO[pnProcInfoNeeded];                    
                    pnProcInfo = pnProcInfoNeeded;
                    // Get the list. 
                    res = RmGetList(handle, out pnProcInfoNeeded, ref pnProcInfo,
                        processInfo, ref lpdwRebootReasons);
                    if (res == 0)
                    {
                        processes = new List<Process>((int)pnProcInfo);
                        // Enumerate all of the results and add them to the  
                        // list to be returned. 
                        for (int i = 0; i < pnProcInfo; i++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                processes.Add(Process.GetProcessById(processInfo[i].
                                    Process.dwProcessId));
                            }
                            // Catch the error in case the process is no longer running. 
                            catch (ArgumentException) { }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource");
                    }
                }
                else if (res != 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not list processes locking resource." +
                                        "Failed to get size of result.");
                }
            }            
            finally
            {
                RmEndSession(handle);
            }
            return processes;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string f = "C:\\some_file.pdf";

            var p = GetLockProcesses(f);

            textBox1.Text = "";
            foreach (Process proc in p)
            {
                textBox1.Text += proc.ProcessName + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            ;

        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    {
        // The product identifier (PID). 
        public int dwProcessId;
        // The creation time of the process. 
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Describes an application that is to be registered with the Restart Manager. 
    /// </summary> 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct RM_PROCESS_INFO
    {
        const int CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME = 255;
        const int CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME = 63;

        // Contains an RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS structure that uniquely identifies the 
        // application by its PID and the time the process began. 
        public RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS Process;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_APP_NAME + 1)]
        // If the process is a service, this parameter returns the  
        // long name for the service. 
        public string strAppName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = CCH_RM_MAX_SVC_NAME + 1)]
        // If the process is a service, this is the short name for the service. 
        public string strServiceShortName;
        // Contains an RM_APP_TYPE enumeration value. 
        public RM_APP_TYPE ApplicationType;
        // Contains a bit mask that describes the current status of the application. 
        public uint AppStatus;
        // Contains the Terminal Services session ID of the process. 
        public uint TSSessionId;
        // TRUE if the application can be restarted by the  
        // Restart Manager; otherwise, FALSE. 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public bool bRestartable;
    }
    /// <summary> 
    /// Specifies the type of application that is described by 
    /// the RM_PROCESS_INFO structure. 
    /// </summary> 
    public enum RM_APP_TYPE
    {
        // The application cannot be classified as any other type. 
        RmUnknownApp = 0,
        // A Windows application run as a stand-alone process that 
        // displays a top-level window. 
        RmMainWindow = 1,
        // A Windows application that does not run as a stand-alone 
        // process and does not display a top-level window. 
        RmOtherWindow = 2,
        // The application is a Windows service. 
        RmService = 3,
        // The application is Windows Explorer. 
        RmExplorer = 4,
        // The application is a stand-alone console application. 
        RmConsole = 5,
        // A system restart is required to complete the installation because 
        // a process cannot be shut down. 
        RmCritical = 1000
    } 

}
```

Работает на ОС начиная с Windows Vista.

Comment: Если файл в сети, я тоже буду видеть, что занят другим процессом?

Comment: @АлександрПузанов смотря что такое "в сети". Для компьютера, с которого файл расшаривается - да (когда файл занят программой с другого компа, будет выводить, что его держит "System"). Если файл на удаленном компьютере и занят процессом с текущего компьютера - выведет нормально имя процесса. Но для произвольного файла занятого процессом с произвольного компа - нет, не работает.

Answer (score 14):

Наиболее трезвый, на мой взгляд, способ понять занят ли файл другим процессом - это попытаться скопировать его и получить `System.IO.IOException` в случае ошибки ввода-вывода, которая как раз таки и будет возникать при отсутствии к нему доступа. Попытки реализовать метод что бы проверить блокирован файл или нет особого результата не дадут. Поскольку никто не гарантирует, что в промежутке между вызовом метода проверки на блокировку и копированием файла ни какой другой процесс его уже не занял.

Comment: Файл создается, записывается, закрывается и больше не используется. Если процесс сторонний и откроет, то только для чтения.

Comment: Так и есть. При копировании бьет исключение. Это то, что нужно. спасибо огромное.

Comment: Файл невозможно удалить. но вот копируется он свободно. К примеру pdf документ, открыт через Adobe Reader.

Comment: +1, единственный правильный метод — выполнить действие и ловить исключения.

Comment: Обычно да, но под эту задачу нашлась специальная либа. Загадочная какая-то, но вроде рабочая.

Comment: VladD, попробуй открыть файл pdf через Adobe Reader и выполни копирование. Исключения нет (и быть не может ) и файл без проблем скопируется. Странно, что столько плючов за данный ответ. Ведь На данный мометнт самый лучший ответ дал VadimTagil.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Скорее всего, Adobe Reader открывает файл с параметром share=ReadWrite, запрещая только удаление файла.  Restart Manager срабатывает, если файл открыт хотя бы "на что-то одно", а ловля исключений - только когда именно требуемая операция недоступна. Можно попробовать ловлю исключений на конструкторе File с параметром FileShare.None, тогда и на ридере должно выбить.

Comment: Честно, пробовал и этот вариант. Так не только с ридером.

Answer (score 4):

Вот готовый [проект.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10760/An-app-to-see-who-has-files-open-on-a-network-serv)
Все делается через системный [openfiles.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb490961.aspx) который находится в `c:\Windows\System32`

Он поддерживает множество операций таких как закрытие файла, запросы и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы хотите получить качественную копию файлов в другой папке, то вам надо изменить алгоритм. Вы можете потерять данные в процессе копирования, вы можете запросить состояние файла (теоретически) одновременно с процессом который этот файл начнет открывать и если тот процесс локальный, то он заблокирует файл, который вы считаете свободным.

Правильный подход в этой задаче - просто попытаться сразу скопировать все, а после завершения копирования проверить результат. Например по длине файлов или по времени их модификации до копирования и после. Файлы, которые не прошли проверку скопировать повторно. Ну и далее - проанализировать и обработать возникшие ошибки.

Comment: Что-то не очень понятно. Стандартный метод File.Copy, как и API-функция CopyFile, блокируют исходный файл на запись, не важно локальный он или сетевой. Повреждение данных при их использовании невозможно.

Comment: Тут только момент, что во время копирования файл может быть открыт на дозапись. Но думаю, это не возможно