# Как определить файлы используемые сторонним процессом?

Tags: c#

Есть папка с 8Гб мелких(1-5мб) файлов. Есть приложение, которое использует один из этих файлов. Мне нужно определить какой файл используется в данный момент.

Я вижу это, как постоянно прослушивание процесса и попытка отловить обращение к winApi на открытие файла. 
Или перебирать все файлы с попыткой открыть для записи.

Оба варианта какие-то иррациональные. Может кто подскажет, как быть в моем случае?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Тут есть несколько вариантов.

- Получить список процессов, открывших файл, с помощью Restart Manager ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/727180/240512)), для каждого файла.
- Распарсить вывод команды `openfiles /query`, которая выводит список всех открытых в данный момент файлов, и отфильтровать нужное (предварительно нужно включить вывод локальных файлов через команду  `openfiles /local on`, и перезагрузить систему).
- Как вы сказали, пытаться открывать файлы с параметром `FileShare.None`, и ловить исключения

Смотрите сами, по ситуации, что больше подходит. Все способы довольно тяжелые, если файлов много.

**Примечание.** Утилита openfiles (предположительно) использует для получения списка локально открытых файлов недокументированные возможности функции `NtQuerySystemInformation` и анализ внутренней структуры дескрипторов, поэтому реализовать самостоятельно эту же функциональность будет слишком трудно. ([Пример решения на С++ с использованием своего драйвера.](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! 
Ковыряю код из примера решения с++.
openfiles как второй вариант, но там надо еще как-то пользователя передать, судя по всему интересующий меня процесс запускается от имени системы.

Comment: Мне вот пришел в голову еще один подход:
При открытии файла сторонняя программа получает хендл файла. И скорее всего где-то его сохраняет. Значит в теории можно порыться в памяти процесса. Определить смещение, в котором сохраняется хендл и в своем софте чекать этот участок памяти.

Или так не получится?

Comment: @АлександрЛи Да, получить хэндлы можно, но само имя файла хранится в памяти, доступной только коду уровня ядра, поэтому без написания своего драйвера его не достать

Comment: Ну судя по всему процесс хранит строкой полный путь к файлу. Удалось найти с помощью Cheat Engine. Жаль я в этом не бум-бум. Полез искать как искать динамический адрес.

Comment: @АлександрЛи то, что вы находите через Cheat Engine - это видимо просто переменная, в которой программа хранит имя файла. Ее наверно можно выяснить, подцепляясь к процессу отладкой и ставя точку останова на функцию CreateFile, но это ненамного проще (если делать программно)

Comment: @WhiteKnight Вроде же через WinApi:
ReadProcessMemory и WriteProcessMemory.
Или это сработает только со статичными участками памяти? А для динамической переменной нужно обязательно подцепляться дебагом к процессу?

Comment: @white Вообще, игрушка забивает всего около 150мб оперативной памяти. Может стоит вычитывать ее полностью через ReadProcessMemory. А далее просто искать по регулярке нужную мне строку(значение переменной)

Comment: @АлександрЛи можно и так. Вопрос в том, как определить, какие именно участки адресного пространства реально используются. Перебирать все адресное пространство наверное будет слишком долго.