# Как получить пути файлов и папок которые на данный момент использует процесс в C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужен метод который мог бы циклический проверять какой файл или папка используется в данный момент процессом и возвращал список для дальнейшего анализа путей. Не так давно узнал про **PerformanceCounter** что частично упростило мне жизнь. Но так и весит этот вопрос, по идеи сам проект завис. Так как концепция моего приложения требует решение данного вопроса . Есть пример чего я хочу достичь это стандартная оснастка **Resource Monitor** под винду. Там есть вкладка *Диск > Работа*  диска просто выбираешь любой процесс и можно увидеть все файлы и папки открытые этим процессом. Собственно поэтому я еще не слился, так как предполагаю что есть API под это дела, **.Net Framework** толстый, ни одной жизни программиста не хватит чтобы все изучить. Любые варианты решения обсудим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просто как идея: у [sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) есть [бесплатная утилита](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle), которая запускается из командной строки, которая может показать все файлы, занятые процессом. Вы можете её скачать и запускать в цикле, считывая вывод в свою программу.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/177146/5045688

Comment: Если любые варианты годятся, то можно попробовать [ETW](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/etw/about-event-tracing). Я немного [щупал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1016677/184217) технологию.

Comment: Уже обсуждалось: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/759165/240512 У Resource Monitor скорее всего тоже свой драйвер про это