# Как понять что файл не занят другим процессом

Tags: c#

Суть проблемы, робот принимает файлы по почте, сохраняет их в директорию, конвертирует в ексель и в конце метода отправляет их на внутри-корпоративную почту. Столкнулся с проблемой, похоже excel не успевает закончить работу с документом и метод отправки пытается его отправить, ловлю :

> [System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()] System.IO.IOException: Процесс не
>   может получить доступ к файлу

Как перед отправкой файла убедится что он свободен? `Sleep` - не нравится подход и не дает 100%.
Вот часть моего кода где ошибка:

```
workSheet.SaveAs(pathToXlsFile);
excelApp.Quit();
//Оповещаем об успешном создании нового файла
Log.Write(null, String.Format("Файл {0} успешно создан", pathToXlsFile));

Attachment attachment = new Attachment(pathToXlsFile);
email.sendEmailLetter("Поступил новый файл", "Поступил новый файл на сервер. Проект EDI.", attachment);
```

Comment: дождитесь выполнения `workSheet.SaveAs(pathToXlsFile);`

Comment: "Как ... убедится что он свободен?" - попробовать эксклюзивно его открыть.

Comment: Справа от вопроса есть блок "Похожее" там первый вариант вам подойдёт

Comment: @Chloroform создать цикл и делать попытки? Ждать пока освободится.

Comment: @DigitalCore а он bool возвращает? Дайте пример, как дождаться?

Comment: дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/691071/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8

Comment: @Zergatul Формально да, но тут скорее у автора проблема "как дождаться окончания чего-то". Для решения этой проблемы средства из того вопроса будут очено неэффективны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public bool IsLocked(string fileName)
{
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            fs.Close();
            // Здесь вызываем свой метод, работаем с файлом
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.HResult == -2147024894)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```csharp
while (IsLocked("имя файла")) ;
```

Comment: Достаточно рискованно ловить [базовое исключение](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ioexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Возможно, файла нет на диске или присутствует другая проблема ввода-вывода требующая отдельного внимания.

Comment: никто не запрещает проверить условие исключения

Comment: @DigitalCore спасибо. Как прикрутить сюда кол-во попыток, условие остановки просто добавить? Есть риск вогнать в вечный цикл.

Comment: @Winteriscoming можете добавить условия: количество попыток, вызвать свой метод прямо из цикла после `Close` и вернуть `false`, можете отловить исключение `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` если `true` вернуть `false` дальше творчество.